# Docusign - editing email address

Tags: docusignapi

I am using Docusign and have an issue with an envelope that has been sent to multiple recipients.  3 have signed electronically but the 4th can not as we have sent it to an invalid email.  I do not have the option to edit the email address when I resend.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the emailaddress of the recipient by doing call to below endpoint

```
PUT https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/recipients?resend_envelope=true

{
  "signers": [
   {
      "recipientId": "3",
      "name": "Signer Name",
      "email": "signercorrectemail@domain.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

In above example name and email will be updated for recipientId - 3. And envelope will be resend to only recipientId 3 only. For details please refer to https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/update/

Answer (score 0):

`Amit K Bist`'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46065817/1219543) shows the Rest Api approach.

There is also an alternate option. You can use the [Advanced Correct](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-correct-documents) feature in Docusign Web console to edit the email address of a recipient.

> You can correct the details of in process envelopes that you sent or are shared with you, including both the recipient and document information.

#### Web Console URL's:

- https://www.docusign.net/
- (Sandbox) https://demo.docusign.net/